# Modelica Issue Tracker submissions rejected as spam

Tags: modelica

I found a minor defect in the MSL3.2.1b4 and wanted to report it through the proper bug [tracker](https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/newticket) for Modelica as is indicated on [GitHub](https://github.com/modelica/Modelica) under Development and Contribution.

Below is an example of what I tried to submit (along with changing the various drop down options that are given). However, when I click submit it is indicated as potential spam with the following message:

"Trac thinks your submission might be Spam. To prove otherwise please provide a response to the following."

But no response option is give to indicate it is not spam. I've tried it in Chrome and Internet Explorer thinking it might be a browser issue but neither attempt worked.

**Question:**

How can one properly contribute to improving Modelica and more specifically Modelica Standard Library?

**Sample:**

'''Defect''': {{{Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialTwoPort}}} has what appears to be an incorrect reference for the visibility option of the white triangle portion of the flow direction arrow.

''Example'': When {{{showDesignFlowDirection = false}}}, the blue portion disappears leaving the white triangle hanging out all alone in space.

'''Suggested Correction'''
replace:
{{{visible=allowFlowReversal}}}
with:
{{{visible=showDesignFlowDirection}}}

Comment: You should send an email to the Modelica.org webmaster: webmaster@modelica.org and state the same as you did here (or add a link to this question). The spam protection seems to be broken and should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and contacted the Modelica.org webmaster.

I got the following response:

"The trac captcha plugin is currently broken so the usual way to gain 
karma to bypass the spam filter does not work."

So that's good to know. Once I'm aware this issue is fixed I will update this answer.